# Symfony 3 access entity manager from another bundle`s repository

Tags: php, symfony

In my project I got 2 bundles (AppBundle and CommonBundle) and 2 different databases, 1 per Bundle. In my config it is shown like this:

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager:   default
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection:       default
            auto_mapping:     true
            naming_strategy:  doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        common:
            connection:       common_data
            auto_mapping:     false
            mappings:
                CommonBundle:     ~
                #FOSUserBundle: ~
            naming_strategy:  doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
```

Now I am in `CommonBundle`s Repository and I want to access `AppBundle`s connection to get some data from its DB, like this:

```
<?php

namespace CommonBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use CommonBundle\Entity\Audit;

class AuditRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  public function MyFunc()
    {
        $em =$this->getEntityManager();
        $em_def =$this->getEntityManager('default');
        $em_def->getRepository('AppBundle:Info')->getInfo('myInfo');//ERROR here
    }
}
```

But instead I get the following error:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\ORMException: "Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle'." at ...
```

So any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the full path because you are in another Bundle
try this or something similar with the full path:

```
$em_def->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Info')->getInfo('myInfo');
```

Comment: Get the following error `The class 'AppBundle\\Entity\\Info' was not found in the chain configured namespaces CommonBundle\\Entity at...`. It is searching `CommonBundle`, not `AppBundle`

Comment: Nope.  Not even close I'm afraid.  A Doctrine repository only knows about it's own entity manager.  No builtin access to other managers.  It would require some fairly complex injecting to make this sort of thing work.  Not worth the effort.

Comment: Try  to add AppBundle in your config before CommonBundle